# Bound Usercontrol does not show up if assigned after view's InitializeComponent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have this Binded Usercontrol in my MainWindowViewModel that does not update in the view when I change it in the code.

MainWindowView.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="HataTracker.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="648" Width="1152">

<Grid>
    <UserControl Content="{Binding ContentView}"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindowView.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public partial class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public UserControl ContentView { set; get; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ContentView = new SearchView();
    }
}
```

#### SearchView is a UserControl

It works fine when i first run the program , i get my SearchView in the ContentView display area

#### The problem is :

If i change content view to something else , say CreateView , my SearchView is going to stay on the screen.

If i don't put a value in ContentView during my MainWindowModelView constructor , it is going to remain blank.

### Question

- How can i swap Binded Usercontrol and have the changes reflected on my view?

Comment: Your ViewModel should **not** contain UI elements, but other ViewModels. remove the `ContentView` property from your ViewModel.

Comment: I have replaced the UserControl ContentView by a BaseViewModel type and i have the same issue , when changing the view model while the application is running , there is no change on my MainWindowView ( which has a Usercontrol bound to the ContentView propertie )

Comment: Raise `NotifyPropertyChanged` in the setter of your property.